# Build transaction offline

Tags: transaction-data

I'm trying to build a transaction hex string which I could later broadcast using the [daemon rpc](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#send_raw_transaction), the [my-monero-core](https://github.com/mymonero/mymonero-core-js) lib doesn't seem to have an API to do, so I used the code that I found [here](https://xmr.llcoins.net/) Eventually I got it to build the following transaction string

> 01000102d0beb08196010100417b816f03f3da689e68f56217bf8d5bd8b858f71b66b84c7e95c19142ecae160280a8d6b90702b02dec621648c4060e40e1a9a774808adf3d678c83a0027e9a2f7313cbd7bd1980f8e7c78d0102ae92396f3c9c2e7d46bf1b6fe102b32036b7953f7fea21817226cc163473e79a21016e8efb46025e60f22d815ce16fe2dad9d9b8620f4faecfe9897a5de056f276af2569ab5d4a413b63d383db6b02faefdf2bbf3c65cf2d1a0efab49e0304e6280f9ef3f62b340dd047b26ff71aa5aff17a475f790ec96b5da7f4d766144cab040d

which according to this [tool](https://xmrchain.net/rawtx) is at least a valid hex string. However when I try to broadcast it I get a response stating either `"invalid_output": true` or `"invalid_input": true` depending on number of `mixin` and destinations that I play with. Unfortunately `boolean` isn't very helpful to figure out what the problem actually is. So the questiond are

1. Is there a well-known valid piece of code to build a transaction hex string given valid UTXOs and spend keys for them? (preferably JS but anything would do)
2. Is the code that I'm using valid? I noticed it builds transactions of `version 1`, are those still supported?

Comment: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/10846/how-does-one-craft-a-monero-transaction-locally-sign-with-their-private-key-and

Comment: @jtgrassie yeah, I've seen that source code, was just hoping maybe there is a way to figure out what's wrong with tx that I built (maybe something simple?) before I spend another week porting the C++ version to potentially get the same result

Comment: The size of your tx is a glaring giveaway it's not going to work as it's only ~200 bytes. A 1 in 2 out with ringsize 11 is nearer 2kb. Next, as you spotted, it's v1, which is not going to work on current mainnet.

Comment: @jtgrassie thanks a lot, looks like that C++ code is the only way then